# COALESCE TSQL with a join tsql

Tags: t-sql

I have a requirement to pick up data that is in more than one place and I have some form of recognition if using the coalesce function. Basically I am looking to coalesce the join itself but looking online its seems as if i can only do this on the fields.

So we have a Products and Suppliers table, we also have these as a temp table so in total 4 tables (products, tempproducts, suppliers, tempsuppliers). In the suppliers and products table is where we store our products and suppliers and their temptables we store any new suppliers/products. We also have a tempsupplierproduct which joins new suppliers to new products. However we can end in a situation where a new supplier has an existing product so the new supplier will be in the tempsuppliers table and its product is in the products table NOT the tempproducts as it is not new, we will also have a new tempsupplierproduct to join the two up.

So i want a query which looks in the tempsupplierproducts table and then gets basic information about the supplier and products. To do this i am using a coalesce.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SP.*, COALESCE(P.Product, PD.Product) 'Product', COALESCE(S.Supplier, SU.Supplier) 'Supplier'
FROM tempsupplierproduct SP
LEFT JOIN tempProduct P ON SP.ProductCode = P.Code
LEFT JOIN Products PD ON SP.ProductCode = PD.Code
LEFT JOIN tempSupplier S ON SP.SupplierCode = S.Code
LEFT JOIN Suppliers SU ON SP.SupplierCode = SU.Code
```

Now while this works, something at the back of my head tells me it is not entirely right, ideally i want if data is not in table A then join to table B. I have seen maybe coalescing inside the join itself but I am unsure how to do this

```
LEFT JOIN Suppliers Su ON SP.SupplierCode = COALESCE(S.Code, SU.Code)
```

maybe away, but I am confused by this, all it is saying is use code in temptable if not there then use supplier code. So what would this mean if we have a code in the temptable, will this try to join on it, if so then this is incorrect also.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union the two suppliers tables together and then join them in one go like this. I'm assuming that there are no duplicates between the two tables in this case but with a bit of extra work that could be resolved as well.

```
WITH AllSuppliers AS
(
SELECT Code, Supplier FROM Suppliers
UNION ALL
SELECT Code, Supplier FROM tempSupplier
)
SELECT DISTINCT SP.*, COALESCE(P.Product, PD.Product) 'Product', S.Supplier
FROM tempsupplierproduct SP
LEFT JOIN tempProduct P ON SP.ProductCode = P.Code
LEFT JOIN Products PD ON SP.ProductCode = PD.Code
LEFT JOIN AllSuppliers S ON SP.SupplierCode = S.Code
```

If you need to handle duplicates in the two suppliers tables then an approach like this should work, essentially we rank the duplicates and then pick the highest ranked result. For two tables you could use a full outer join between the two but this approach will scale to any number of tables.

```
WITH AllSuppliers AS
(
SELECT Code, Supplier, 1 AS TablePriority FROM Suppliers
UNION ALL
SELECT Code, Supplier, 2 AS TablePriority FROM tempSupplier
),
SuppliersRanked AS
(
SELECT Code, Supplier,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY TablePriority) AS RowPriority
FROM AllSuppliers
)
SELECT DISTINCT SP.*, COALESCE(P.Product, PD.Product) 'Product', S.Supplier
FROM tempsupplierproduct SP
LEFT JOIN tempProduct P ON SP.ProductCode = P.Code
LEFT JOIN Products PD ON SP.ProductCode = PD.Code
LEFT JOIN SuppliersRanked S ON SP.SupplierCode = S.Code
    AND RowPriority = 1
```

Comment: If you change `UNION ALL` to `UNION` duplicates from `Suppliers` and `tempSupplier` would be removed.

Comment: True, as long as there aren't differences in the Supplier field for one code between the two tables UNION will do the job.

Comment: is there a way to union two up but have one table take precedence over the other

Comment: I've added an alternative version with an approach that picks out the duplicates.

Comment: Hi i assume the Left join on AllSuppliers should actually be SuppliersRanked. Is this correct?

Comment: Tank you very much, been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely join on a coalesced field. Here is a snippet from one of my production views:

```
LEFT JOIN [Portal].tblHelpdeskresource supplier ON PO.fld_str_SupplierID = supplier.fld_str_SupplierID
-- Job type a
    LEFT JOIN [Portal].tblHelpDeskFault HDF ON PO.fld_int_HelpdeskFaultID = HDF.fld_int_ID
    -- Job Type b
    LEFT JOIN [Portal].tblProjectHeader PH ON PO.fld_int_ProjectHeaderID = PH.fld_int_ID 
    LEFT JOIN [Portal].tblPPMScheduleLine PSL ON PH.fld_int_PPMScheduleRef = PSL.fld_int_ID
    -- Managers (used to be separate for a & b type, now converged)
    LEFT JOIN [Portal].uvw_HelpDeskSiteManagers PSM ON COALESCE(PSL.fld_int_StoreID,HDF.fld_int_StoreID) = PSM.PortalSiteId
    LEFT JOIN [Portal].tblHelpdeskResource PHDR ON PSM.PortalResourceId = PHDR.fld_int_ID
```